# NLTK wordnet does not contain vocabulary term - Python

Tags: python, nltk, wordnet

A function in my program finds the definitions of certain vocabulary words, which will be useful for other parts of my program. However, it seems that not every vocabulary word is present in wordnet. 
I find the definitions as follows:

```
y = wn.synset(w + '.n.01').definition()
```

where 'w' is one of the many vocabulary words being fed from a list (did not include rest of the program because it has too much irrelevant code). When the list reaches the term 'ligase', however, the following error comes up:

> line 1298, in synset
>       raise WordNetError(message % (lemma, pos))
>       nltk.corpus.reader.wordnet.WordNetError: no lemma 'ligase' with part of speech 'n'

Is there anyway to bypass this or a different way to find the definition of these terms not in wordnet? My program is going through various scientific terms, so this may occur more often as I add more words to the list.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should not make an assumption that a word is known to WordNet. Check if there are any relevant synsets, and ask for a definition only if there is at least one:

```
for word in ["ligase", "world"]: # Your word list
    ss = wn.synsets(word)
    if ss:
        definition = ss[0].definition() 
        print("{}: {}".format(word, definition))
    else:
        print("### Word {} not found".format(word))

#### Word ligase not found
#world: everything that exists anywhere
```